# Why does ViewModel.getStore("Key") return null?

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs5

The previous version was incorrect. My apologies.

I'm trying to load a store from the server with some parameters.

```
onSave: function (cmp) {

  var vm = cmp.up('stageform').getViewModel();
  vm.set("extraParams", {applicationFormId: 1});
  var store = vm.getStore("applicationForms");

  console.log(store);
}
```

`vm.getStore("applicationForms");` returns null when the event is fired the first time, after that it returns the actual instance of the store.

Why do I get such a strange behavior? And is this the proper way of loading data from the server?

ViewModel Code:

```
Ext.define('CPCApplication.view.cases.ApplicationFormModel', {
   .....

    stores: {
        applicationForms: {
            model: 'CPCApplication.model.ApplicationForm',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                extraParams: '{extraParams}',
                autoload: true,
                url: ...,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            },
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious error in the code you posted. I only not quite sure when you call getStore. That can be important because view model exists only together with its view, binding is asynchronous, etc. Thus, it may be (theoretically) that the store really does not yet exist the first time.

Ideally, prepare a showcase and post it to https://fiddle.sencha.com. Then it would be possible to sort out if it is a problem in your app or in Ext. (Btw, which version?)